# Update External Sharing Setting via powershell for a modern site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, pnp-powershell, external-sharing

I am looking for some help with pnp powershell to see if below would be possible to do:

- Once a modern team site collection is created, I would like to set Sharing setting for the same to 'New and Existing Guests', see screenshot below. In my tenant, it defaults to 'Existing Guests' when a site is created so I want that to change to NEw and existing guests via powershell.

[image]

Can someone please help with powershell script to perform the same if its doable, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is only settable by using the SPO cmdlets as this is an administrator-level setting.

You can use [Set-SPOSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps).

```
Connect-SPOService https://tenantName-admin.sharepoint.com
Set-SPOSite https://tenantName.sharepoint.com/sites/siteCollection -SharingCapability ExistingExternalUserSharingOnly
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Trevor. I want to set it to 'new and existing guests', what would be the parameter for that. I believe ExistingExternalUserSharingOnly would set it to 'Existing guests only' option.

Comment: See the cmdlet help I linked. It provides the information you need.